# Rails: CSS: requiring css/scss associated with controller page view through application.css.scss

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3

So I removed the /= requiretree line from the original application.css.scss
but now I have to stylesheet_link_tag in each page for the specific .css since it's not requiring every single css file (as intended)

my question: how do I require in each specific controller view just the stylesheet rails associates with that controller? Is it some line I put in application.css.scss?

Again, I do NOT want every stylesheet loaded in every page which is why I removed requiretree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] in layout and for production config assets pipeline to compile all files separatly